# javascript inside titanium studio: 'new' in objects

Tags: javascript, titanium, new-operator

I have the following code in a non-browser environment (Titanium Studio) and I noticed that both result1 and result2 work, return the same result, and are the same type (object).

Could you explain if they are different in any and how they are different?

In my case inside name1 there is no reference to the local context (no 'this' in there, just local variables) and I am trying to figure out if I should be writing all my code with or without 'new' when I have a situation like the one below.

```
var name1 = function(some_arg){
    // some stuff
    return result; // returns an object
}

var result1 = name1('some_value');
var result2 = new name1('some_value');

typeof(result1); // returns object
typeof(result2); // returns object
```

Thanks!

**Edit Below: The original question was answered and I am now looking for a clarification on something related.**

Code related to comment below:

```
function Name1 (name){
    this.name = name;
}
var version1 = new Name1('joey');
version1.name;

var Name2 = function(name){
    this.name = name
}
var version2 = new Name2('joey');
version2.name;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is bound to a new object when using `new` while it is bound to the global object when not using `new`. If you do not use `this` in the constructor function or any methods you add to your object, it indeed does not really matter - however, you should use it anyway or you'll have a problem if you ever do use it.

Comment: great. thanks! if i am using the function as a constructor is:

 var name = function(){}

the same as:

 function name(){}
 
? 

thanks.

Comment: No, that's just assigning the function to a variable, pretty similar to `function name() {}` (except being hoisted to the top of the scope) - Using a function as a constructor means *calling* it with `new`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little confused now. I am going to rephrase the question... I added another snippet of code to the original question above (the new code is below the bold edit comment). So both version1.name and version2.name above return 'joey'. Are they any different? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Well they have different constructor functions. Pretty much like two different classes which are the same besides the class name.